# Terraform GCP Backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

while creating backend in gcp using terraform getting below errors.

Error loading state: Failed to open state file at gs://tf-state-demo/demo-terraform.state/default.tfstate: googleapi: got HTTP response code 403 with body: `AccessDenied`Access denied.service account does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

i have given full storage admin role to service account used for creating bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with your environment configuration. Terraform use the application default credentials (ADC), therefore you need to create the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` equal to the absolute path of your service account key file.

If you want to avoid to use service account key file (and you have right, because of security reasons), you can use your own credential by doing `gcloud auth application-default login`

*Note: the environment variable has the highest precedence on any other ADC modes*

Answer (score -2):

Sure, here's a summarized version in Markdown format:

---

### GCP Authentication Methods for Terraform

#### 1. Authentication Commands

- **`gcloud auth login`**

  - For Google Cloud SDK and interactive GCP operations.
  - Grants user-specific permissions via CLI.
- **`gcloud auth application-default login`**

  - For local applications and development environments.
  - Generates credentials for programmatic GCP access.

#### 2. Terraform and GCP

- **Terraform uses Application Default Credentials (ADC).**
- **Environment Variable**: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

  - Points to the service account key file for Terraform authentication.

#### 3. Best Practices

- Use **`gcloud auth application-default login`** for Terraform.

  - Aligns with Terraform's ADC requirement for GCP resource management.
- `gcloud auth login` is more suited for direct GCP SDK interactions.

#### 4. ADC File

- check this path `~/.config/gcloud`. You get credential from ADC.json

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTwpE.png)

Ref:

1. [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)
2. [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)